# Center embedded video content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to center the youtube video on this page:

http://www.cultcitychi.com/event/interpol-the-riv/

by using a variation of this code

```
.post_content iframe {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

The code above works on "post_content" and I need it to work on the content of this events page. I can't figure out how to generate the proper tag for it.

Comment: `.jetpack-video-wrapper` has a `margin-left` of `-170px`..remove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `margin-left: -170px;` property from style.css?ver=4.0 that is directly affecting this element.

One of the inherited property seems to be interfering with the layout of the player.

[Here is a screenshot that shows the property that I am referring to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L67x.png)

Simply removing this property aligns the player to the centre on my browser

Comment: that worked.  but how did you find that jetpack tag upon inspection?  im having trouble re-creating that in chrome

Comment: Just before the flash player loads, right click the black space, "Inspect element". Then keep moving up the parent containers till you find `<div class="jetpack-video-wrapper">`

Answer (score 2):

You have a `margin-left:-170px` set on it right now.  So to center your video, include

```
.entry-content .jetpack-video-wrapper { margin-left:0; }
```

in style.css.

Comment: Was just about to post this as well.

Comment: how would I then go about centering the image on the post?